# Python 3 Tkinter, Create window if window is not already created

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been creating a very simple password generator. In the brackets `var` is the password which has been generated. I have been trying to create a window for my output. The Idea is if the window exists then the program lifts the window. Otherwise it creates the window. Then the program creates a label which is the password.

The Issue is, it creates a new window every time.

```
def outpt_(var):
    try: 
        outpt.lift()
    except:
        outpt = tk.Toplevel()
        outpt.title("Output Secure")
        outpt.geometry("350x120")
    outpot = tk.Label(outpt, text = var, font=("DejaVu Sans", 11)).pack()
```

Comment: Keep track yourself of whether the window has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

`outpt` is a local variable in the function.

> The issue is, it creates a new window every time.

That's because it will always raise `NameError` exception. The next time you call this function.`python` wouldn't find your `outpt`.

Three solutions:

1. Use a global variable.
2. Use OOP
3. You also could try:

```
root = tk.Tk()

def outpt_(var):
    try: 
        root.outpt.lift()
    except:
        root.outpt = tk.Toplevel()
        root.outpt.title("Output Secure")
        root.outpt.geometry("350x120")
    outpot = tk.Label(root.outpt, text = var, font=("DejaVu Sans", 11)).pack()
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated. the `tk.Toplevel()` will **always** create a new window, even if it is the same variable name.

Comment: Also, please elaborate on _Use OOP_.

Comment: @10Rep Why?** the tk.Toplevel() will always create a new window.**Have you tested it?Not matter the `Use OOP`.The third solution could work normally.

Comment: I don't need to test it. It will do what I say. Have you tested it?

Comment: It does not create a new window every time. This worked

Comment: @10Rep Do you know why `try...except..` won't work normally?That's because the code will always raise `NameError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it generates a new window every time is that when you call `tk.Toplevel`, it creates a new window. Even if name it the same thing, it won't recall it, it will create a new one.

I think you need to use `.withdraw()`. The idea is you create the window at the beginning, then you `.withdraw()` it. This will simply hide it, and when you need it back you can use `.deiconify()`.

Read about [`.withdraw()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/Tkinter.Tk.withdraw) and [`deiconify()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm).

Full code:

```py
def outpt_(var):
    try: 
        outpt.withdraw()
    except:
        outpt.deiconify()
    outpt = tk.Label(outpt, text = var, font=("DejaVu Sans", 11)).pack()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `tk.Toplevel` does not create a new window every time. The other solution is simpler. This will definitely come in useful.